# Python Bot error message

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

This is my code and I added error handling, but it's not working. I'm getting an error in bash when the command is executed by a non-admin. Below command if I type `?hello` with admin role it works, but when a non-admin types that commands, they receive `You don't have permission to use this command.`

```
token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
prefix = "?"

import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix)
bot.remove_command("help")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def on_command_error(self, exception, ctx):
    if isinstance(exception, CheckFailure):
        print("{0} does not have permission to run `{1}`".format(ctx.message.author, ctx.command.name))
    elif isinstance(exception, CommandNotFound):
        # This is handled in CustomCommands
        pass
    else:
        print(exception)
        await self.on_error("on_command_error", exception, ctx) 

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_any_role("Admin", "Moderator")
async def hello(ctx):
    msg = 'Hello... {0.author.mention}'.format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)

bot.run(token)
```

Comment: "i getting error can't run script". So when you run this program, it prints exactly "can't run script", and nothing else?

Comment: You *"tried all codes from internet"*? That is a lot of codes ;)

Comment: yes tried but no idea were i doing wrong. I know something i doing wrong.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't like your `await` keyword, there. AFAICT `await` can only appear inside async functions, and `on_command_error` hasn't been marked as async. (posting this as a comment and not an answer because I don't know enough about async and/or discord to know whether this completely solves the problem)

Comment: I added async now updated main script and it runs but can't receive custom error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`on_command_error` must be a coroutine, and you must register it as an event with your `bot`

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, commands.NoPrivateMessage):
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.author, 'This command cannot be used in private messages.')
    elif isinstance(error, commands.DisabledCommand):
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.author, 'Sorry. This command is disabled and cannot be used.')
    elif isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.author, 'Sorry. You dont have permission to use this command.')
    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        command = ctx.message.content.split()[1]
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "Missing an argument: " + command)
    elif isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, codify("I don't know that command"))
```

Comment: really great bro your's all reply is awesome everything works.